# Android_id to guid?

Tags: android

I am using Secure.Android_Id for getting unique id of the device. But I need to pass it to as GUID for a service. Is there a easy way to create that?

The basic code I wrote looks something like **this**:

`String android_id = getAndroidId();
        long leastSignificantBits = 0;
        long mostSignificantBits = 0;
        UUID uuid = null;`

```
    if (android_id != null) {
        String asciiConvertedText = "";
        int len = android_id.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            asciiConvertedText += "" + ((short) android_id.charAt(i));
        }

        len = asciiConvertedText.length();
        if (len > 16) {
            leastSignificantBits = Long.parseLong(asciiConvertedText.substring(0, 15));

            if (asciiConvertedText.length() > 31) {
                mostSignificantBits = Long.parseLong(asciiConvertedText.substring(16, 31));
            } else {
                mostSignificantBits = Long.parseLong(asciiConvertedText.substring(32,
                        asciiConvertedText.length()));
            }

            uuid = new UUID(mostSignificantBits, leastSignificantBits);
        } else if (len > 0) {

            leastSignificantBits = Long.parseLong(asciiConvertedText);
            uuid = new UUID(mostSignificantBits, leastSignificantBits);
        } else {
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        }
    }

    if (uuid != null) {
        deviceUUID = uuid.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `new UUID(Secure.Android_Id.hashCode(), Secure.Android_Id.hashCode()`?

Edited: here's my code for "unique" id:

```
public static String getDeviceId() {
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)Globals.Line2App.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = "" + Secure.getString(Globals.Line2App.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
    return deviceUuid.toString();
}
```

I'm not sure if the above helps you, but I use a composite of several values (I think I got this code from another thread here on stackoverflow).

Comment: wow.. that helps.. Is there someway I can differentiate most significant bits and least significant bits for hashcode?

Comment: Well, a UUID represents 128 bits and a hash code reduces the string to 32 bits. So, you don't really need the extra bits.

Comment: Dhaag23, just occurred to me - hashcode isn't unique across multiple instances of JVM. Hence we cannot guarantee the same hashcode is sent for the string when the user launches the app again and tries to connect to the service. since I had already accepted the answer for this question, didn't want to edit the question. so posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476967/android-id-to-guid-across-sessions If you have any suggestions, please post the answer there.